# C# System Service Configuration Best Practice

Tags: c#, configuration

System services run their EXEs from the C:\Windows\System32 directory, and thus if I want to have my service load a configuration file, I need to place the config file in the System32 directory, which just doesn't feel right. My understanding of System32 is that it should only be touched through system utilities, and isn't a place for an application to place its supporting files. Is there a best practice for how C# system services load configuration files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of placing windows service configuration file inside System32 directory. In fact if you create new windows service project and add project properties/settings (AssemblyName.exe.config) this configuration file will be placed on installation path (default settings for service installer).

I believe installation path is the best place for configuration file.

Configuration file can easily be extended by your own type of settings. Take a look at one of my answers:

[Custom configuration section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676374/custom-configuration-section/12677402#12677402)